# Angular 2 - Argument type RequestOptions is not assignable to parameter type RequestOptions

Tags: http, angular, service, injectable

I try to create cutom Http class to hadle 401 error globaly. I have error when call super constructor - **Argument type RequestOptions is not assignable to parameter type RequestOptions**.

Here is my code:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {
  private baseUrl: string;

  constructor(baseUrl: string, backend: ConnectionBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    super(backend, options); // <- Error here
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('get...');
    return super.get(this.baseUrl.concat(url), options).catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    console.log(error['status']);

    return Observable.throw(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks correct. I have the same constructor in one of my classes and it works. Make sure you have everything all the right packages installed. That said, you have an unrelated error which is using `this` before calling `super()`

Comment: I create new file with same code and appear new error - 'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class. After I paste "super" before "this" everything works fine. Thanks

Comment: Check out here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419987/angular2-provide-custom-http-not-working/46549420#46549420